# Dump sqlalchemy objects/fixtures as insert statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, fixture

I'm programmatically generating test data, both as sqlalchemy ORM objects, and as [fixtures](http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture). However, other parts of the application need to have the test data pre-loaded in the database, as sql INSERT statements (don't question this - it's a fixed requirement whether or not you or I like it). I'd like to take my generated objects, or fixtures, and dump them as insert statements. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: SQLAlchemy has no easy way to generate the queries with the values. Can't you load them into a database and dump from there?

Comment: @PedroWerneck Well, that might be the way to go. I'll certainly appreciate any suggestion you may have for a good to tool perform such a dump from DB2 on linux.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MartinThoma It's been a long time, but I ended up doing a lot of low level hacking of libraries in this period. I'd suggest logging the generated insert statements when running the fixtures.